# AnsiString as default for type string in Embarcadero C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder, unicode-string, ansistring

I have inherited an old Borland C++ Builder application which I now must migrate to a new development tool. The suggested way to go is with Embarcadero C++ Builder, and from my initial tests it seems like a rather smooth transition.

I do however have one problem to which I'm hoping there is a simple solution:

The application parses a large amount of text files. These files are all ANSI based, and that will never change, so it is ANSI in and ANSI out. The main problem I have is that with Embarcadero C++, the type `string` is now a `UnicodeString` instead of an `AnsiString` (as it was in Borland C++ Builder).

Using Unicode in this application is not an option - the files it work with are ANSI formatted. Modifying the code to use `AnsiString` (and similar) is doable, but i'd rather not since it uses a lot of `TStringList` (and similar) constructs.

So my question is: Is there a setting or compiler option or something that I can use to tell Embarcadero to use `System.AnsiString` as definition for `string` instead of `System.UnicodeString`?

This is probably a long-shot, but the RAD Studio XE (which is the older version that I have borrowed to make a few tests) documentation says "*by default*, the type `string` is now a Unicode string", which implies that this can be changed. That is however rephrased in the documentation for the current version (XE8), so...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the `UnicodeString` for this purpose. `UnicodeString` and `AnsiString` are both specializations of the template `AnsiStringT`, where the template parameter is the code page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have inherited an old Borland C++ Builder application which I now must migrate to a new development tool. The suggested way to go is with Embarcadero C++ Builder

Yes.  They are actually the same product.  Borland created a child company named CodeGear to manage its developer tools (Delphi, C++Builder, etc), and then Embarcadero later bought CodeGear.

> The main problem I have is that with Embarcadero C++, the type string is now a UnicodeString instead of an AnsiString (as it was in Borland C++ Builder).

`string` (lowercase s) refers to the STL's `std::string` class, which is still `char`-based.  You are thinking of C++Builder's `System::String` alias, which does now map to `System::UnicodeString` instead of `System::AnsiString` (that change was made in C++Builder 2009, when `UnicodeString` was introduced).  However, `AnsiString` still exists and can be used directly.

> Using Unicode in this application is not an option - the files it work with are ANSI formatted.

Then don't use `UnicodeString` to process them.  Continue using `AnsiString` instead.

> Modifying the code to use AnsiString (and similar) is doable, but i'd rather not since it uses a lot of TStringList (and similar) constructs.

That, on the other hand, would be a problem, yes.  Most of the RTL only supports `UnicodeString` now.  So code using `TStringList` will have to be re-written, such as by using `TList<AnsiString>` or `std::vector<AnsiString>` instead (unless the code is utilizing the `TStringList::(Comma|Delimited)Text` properties, in which case you have a bigger re-write).  However, for `AnsiString` parsing code, many of the older `AnsiString`-based RTL functions were moved to a separate `System.AnsiStrings` unit, so you can add `#include <System.AnsiStrings.hpp>` to your code to reach them.

> So my question is: Is there a setting or compiler option or something that I can use to tell Embarcadero to use System.AnsiString as definition for string instead of System.UnicodeString?

No.  And if you think about it, that would be a major undertaking for them to implement.  Multiple copies of the RTL/VCL/FMX frameworks, 2 for each supported OS platform.  And a lot of internal code would have to be IFDEF'ed to handle differences between Ansi/Unicode processing logic.  So not really feasible or cost-effective for them to do (and much too late at this point, especially considering that `AnsiString` is not supported on mobile OS platforms - though there is a 3rd party patch available to re-enable it).

> This is probably a long-shot, but the RAD Studio XE (which is the older version that I have borrowed to make a few tests) documentation says "by default, the type string is now a Unicode string", which implies that this can be changed.

No, it cannot by changed.  The RTL/VCL/FMX frameworks are Unicode now.  But that does not require that your code must be Unicode as well.  Only in the spots where you need to directly interact with the RTL/VCL/FMX.  The rest of your code can continue using `AnsiString` (or even `std::string`) as needed.

Comment: Not quite the quick fix I was hoping for, but I knew that was a long-shot. A really good and extensive answer non the less! I understand the problem better now and have enough clues to believe that I can pull this off without too much work. So thank you, Remy!

Answer (score 1):

Probably I've got bad news. They always talk about migration, nowhere about quick fix.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Enabling_Applications_for_Unicode
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Enabling_C%2B%2B_Applications_for_Unicode

Well... I hate Strings in Borland. Who the hell came up with to number them from 1 instead from 0?!

Comment: Delphi strings are 1-indexed (except on mobile platforms, where they are 0-indexed by default, but there is a Dephi compiler directive to change that). The RTL/VCL/FMX frameworks are written in Delphi, not in C++.  The C++ `System::AnsiString` and `System::UnicodeString` classes are just compatible wrappers for Delphi's native string types, so they have to use the same indexing.

Answer (score 0):

**AnsiString**-s can be converted into **UnicodeString**-s easily. This is how I handled the conversion. Old C++Builder 2007 code:

```
void __fastcall TFormVidya::lbEntData(TWinControl *Control, int Index, AnsiString &Data)
{
    if(FEntNameSto) {
        char *pc;
        int len=FEntNameSto->PeekValue(Index,&pc);
        Data.printf("DB %.*s",len,pc);
    } else Data.sprintf("MOCK %d!",Index);
}
```

Converted for C++Builder XE2:

```
void __fastcall TFormVidya::lbEntData(TWinControl *Control, int Index, UnicodeString &Data)
{
    if(FEntNameSto) {
        char *pc;
        int len=FEntNameSto->PeekValue(Index,&pc);
        AnsiString astr;
        astr.printf("DB %.*s",len,pc);
        Data=astr;
    } else Data.sprintf(L"MOCK %d!",Index);
}
```

The essence is the assignement of an **AnsiString** to an **UnicodeString**: `Data=astr;`.

Also, the help page *ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe2/libraries/System.UnicodeString.html* (the one that says "By default, variables declared as type String are UnicodeString."), also says "**Despite its name, UnicodeString can represent both ANSI character set strings and Unicode strings.**", but I could not make any use of it.